# Wordpress media uploads are owned by user nobody

Tags: wordpress, permissions, media

I goofed and deleted my public_html folder, I had a copy on a different computer and I ftp them over to the server and everything works well accept the media upload.

So my wordpress media uploads gave me an error could not make dir. check permissions. so I 777 the whole directory (unsafe i know) and I successfully uploaded a media file. i look at the new directory it created and the media file and come to find out the directory and image are permissions 777 and owned by user nobody group nobody.

I ran  and its run by the user i want.

How do I get it so wordpress uploads on a user let alone the one I want??

Comment: Which user runs php?

Comment: the user i can ssh in as its a custom user called partners i would tell you who is running apache but i cant use top as this user no /bin access :) its fun